# Does get-childItem -recurse -include return different objects than get-childItem -recurse?

Tags: powershell, filesystems

Here's a simple PowerShell script whose output I cannot explain.

Both `foreach` loops return `System.IO.FileInfo` objects, yet the objects of the first loop, when cast to a `string`, evaluate to a full and absolute path, the objects of the second `forach` loop to a bare filename only:

```
foreach ($file in get-childItem . -recurse -include *.ps1) {
  [string] $name  = $file
   $name 

   $file.GetType().FullName
}


foreach ($file in get-childItem . -recurse          *.ps1) {
  [string] $name  = $file
   $name

   $file.GetType().FullName
}
```

I am puzzled over this behavior. Apparantly, the returned objects are different, yet I cannot find any difference between them.

Comment: It seems like `-Include`, which makes PowerShell filter on the objects name property **afterwards** also changes the default `.ToString()` on these objects, whereas `-Filter`, which filters **while** processing does not. That same behavior happens when you omit `-Include` and use a Where-Object instead like `foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem . -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.ps1' })) {..}`

Answer (score 0):

If you run `$cmdDef = Get-Command Get-ChildItem` and you check `$cmdDef.ParameterSet` you will see the following:

```
    Parameter Name: Path
    ParameterType = System.String[]
    Position = 0
    IsMandatory = False
    IsDynamic = False
    HelpMessage =
    ValueFromPipeline = True
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = True
    ValueFromRemainingArguments = False
    Aliases = {}
    Attributes =


  Parameter Name: Filter
    ParameterType = System.String
    Position = 1
    IsMandatory = False
    IsDynamic = False
    HelpMessage =
    ValueFromPipeline = False
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = False
    ValueFromRemainingArguments = False
    Aliases = {}
    Attributes =
```

Have a look at the [Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#position-argument) attribute.

Basically what's happening, in the first example the `*.ps1` is passed to the `-include` parameter, whereas in the second example it is passed to the `-filter` parameter.

To see the difference between `-include` and `-filter` have a look at the documentation of the [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2)